# How return JSON in ShouldInterceptRequest on android (it always return string)

Tags: android, webview, f#

When returning json from:

```
override this.ShouldInterceptRequest(view:WebView, request:IWebResourceRequest) =
    let rows = Customer.fakeData 1

    let st = Shared.jsonToStream(rows)
    new WebResourceResponse("text/json", "UTF-8", st)
```

It show on the page as an string, no a json object. I also try with `"application/javascript"`.